# How to inject a repository object in custom ViewModel class using Dagger2 and Java?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I want to inject a `MyRepository` object directly into my `ViewModel` class but I always get a `NullPointerException`. This is what I have tried.

This is my `AppModule` class:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    static Retrofit provideRetrofitInstance(){
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    static MyApi provideMyApi(Retrofit retrofit){
        return retrofit.create(MyApi.class);
    }

    @Provides
    static MyRepository provideMyRepository(MyApi myApi) {
        return new MyRepository(myApi);
    }
}
```

And this is the class where I want to get injected:

```
@Singleton
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    @Inject MyRepository myRepository; //Is not injected!!!
    LiveData<Data> myLiveData;

    MyViewModel(Application application, City city) {
        super(application);
        myLiveData = myRepository.addDataToLiveData(city);
    }

    LiveData<Data> getLiveData() {
        return myLiveData;
    }
}
```

And this is my repository class:

```
public class MyRepository {
    private MyApi myApi;

    public MyRepository(MyApi myApi) {
        this.myApi = myApi;
    }

    LiveData<Data> addDataToLiveData(City city) {
        //Make api call
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make your repository constructor inject-able

```
public class MyRepository {
private MyApi myApi;

@Inject 
public MyRepository(MyApi myApi) {
    this.myApi = myApi;
}

LiveData<Data> addDataToLiveData(City city) {
    //Make api call
} }
```

and remove this provider of repository  from module

```
  @Provides
static MyRepository provideMyRepository(MyApi myApi) {
    return new MyRepository(myApi);
}
```

App Module

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    static Retrofit provideRetrofitInstance(){
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    static MyApi provideMyApi(Retrofit retrofit){
        return retrofit.create(MyApi.class);
    }
}
```

and remove Singleton annotation from  viewModel

```
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    @Inject MyRepository myRepository; //Is not injected!!!
    LiveData<Data> myLiveData;

    MyViewModel(Application application, City city) {
        super(application);
        myLiveData = myRepository.addDataToLiveData(city);
    }

    LiveData<Data> getLiveData() {
        return myLiveData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try and get back to you.

Comment: did you remove this from app module

 @Provides
static MyRepository provideMyRepository(MyApi myApi) {
    return new MyRepository(myApi);
}

Comment: Yes, I did and tried to inject the `myApi` directly in constructor in `MyRepository` but it doesn't work.

Comment: why you add singleton on viewmodel ?
make sure you are getting viewmodel object using
ViewModelProvider

Comment: This the way I'm constructing the object, using `ViewModelProvider`. I deleted that Singleton annotation.

Comment: you providing viewmodel Module  like below ?

`@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule{

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(LoginViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindLoginViewModel(loginViewModel: LoginViewModel): ViewModel

   } `

Comment: I'm having a class for that. Can provide a Java code. I'm not familiar with Kotlin. But remember I only need the AppModule.

Comment: Your ViewModel's constructor also has to be injectable and put myrepository into the constructor of the ViewModel

Comment: You don't need `@Provides` method for classes that have `@Inject` annotated constructor...